# C++ scoping error

Tags: c++

I have the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Student.h" <-- fixed the problem
#include "SortedList.h" <-- fixed the problem

using namespace std;

int main() {
    // points to the sorted list object
    SortedList *list = new SortedList;   //This is line 17

    // array to hold 100 student objects
    Student create[100];

    int num = 100000;   // holds different ID numbers

    // fills an array with 100 students of various ID numbers
    for (Student &x : create) {
        x = new Student(num);
        num += 100;
    }

    // insert all students into the sorted list
    for (Student &x : create)
        list->insert(&x);

    delete list;
    return 0;
}
```

And I keep getting the compile time error:

```
main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
main.cpp:17: error: ‘SortedList’ was not declared in this scope
main.cpp:17: error: ‘list’ was not declared in this scope
main.cpp:17: error: expected type-specifier before ‘SortedList’
main.cpp:17: error: expected `;' before ‘SortedList’
main.cpp:20: error: ‘Student’ was not declared in this scope
main.cpp:20: error: expected primary-expression before ‘]’ token
main.cpp:20: error: expected `;' before ‘create’
main.cpp:25: error: expected `;' before ‘x’
main.cpp:31: error: expected primary-expression before ‘for’
main.cpp:31: error: expected `;' before ‘for’
main.cpp:31: error: expected primary-expression before ‘for’
main.cpp:31: error: expected `)' before ‘for’
main.cpp:31: error: expected `;' before ‘x’
main.cpp:34: error: type ‘<type error>’ argument given to ‘delete’, expected pointer
main.cpp:35: error: expected primary-expression before ‘return’
main.cpp:35: error: expected `)' before ‘return’
```

My Student.cpp and SortedList.cpp files compile just fine. They both also include .h files. I just do not understand why I get an error on that line. It seems to be a small issue though. Any insight would be appreciated.

UPDATE1: I originally had .h files included, but i changed it when trying to figure out the cause of the error. The error remains with the .h files included though.

UPDATE2:

**SortedList.h**

```
#ifndef SORTEDLIST_H
#define SORTEDLIST_H

#include "Student.h"

/*
 * SortedList class
 *
 * A SortedList is an ordered collection of Students.  The Students are ordered
 * from lowest numbered student ID to highest numbered student ID.
 */
class SortedList {

  public:

    SortedList();
    // Constructs an empty list.

    SortedList(const SortedList & l);
    // Constructs a copy of the given student object

    ~SortedList();
    // Destructs the sorted list object

    const SortedList & operator=(const SortedList & l);
    // Defines the assignment operator between two sorted list objects

    bool insert(Student *s);
    // If a student with the same ID is not already in the list, inserts 
    // the given student into the list in the appropriate place and returns
    // true.  If there is already a student in the list with the same ID
    // then the list is not changed and false is returned.

    Student *find(int studentID);
    // Searches the list for a student with the given student ID.  If the
    // student is found, it is returned; if it is not found, NULL is returned.

    Student *remove(int studentID);
    // Searches the list for a student with the given student ID.  If the 
    // student is found, the student is removed from the list and returned;
    // if no student is found with the given ID, NULL is returned.
    // Note that the Student is NOT deleted - it is returned - however,
    // the removed list node should be deleted.

    void print() const;
    // Prints out the list of students to standard output.  The students are
    // printed in order of student ID (from smallest to largest), one per line

  private:

    // Since Listnodes will only be used within the SortedList class,
    // we make it private.
    struct Listnode {    
      Student *student;
      Listnode *next;
    };

    Listnode *head; // pointer to first node in the list

    static void freeList(Listnode *L);
    // Traverses throught the linked list and deallocates each node

    static Listnode *copyList(Listnode *L);
    // Returns a pointer to the first node within a particular list
};

#endif
```

**Student.h**

```
#ifndef STUDENT_H
#define STUDENT_H
/*
 * Student class
 *
 * A Student object contains a student ID, the number of credits, and an
 * overall GPA.
 */
class Student {

  public:

    Student();
    // Constructs a default student with an ID of 0, 0 credits, and 0.0 GPA.

    Student(int ID);
    // Constructs a student with the given ID, 0 credits, and 0.0 GPA.

    Student(int ID, int cr, double grPtAv);
    // Constructs a student with the given ID, number of credits, and GPA.\

    Student(const Student & s);
    // Constructs a copy of another student object

    ~Student();
    // Destructs a student object

    const Student & operator=(const Student & rhs);
    // Defines the assignment operator between two student objects

    // Accessors
    int getID() const;       // returns the student ID
    int getCredits() const;  // returns the number of credits
    double getGPA() const;   // returns the GPA

    // Other methods

    void update(char grade, int cr);
    // Updates the total credits and overall GPA to take into account the
    // additions of the given letter grade in a course with the given number
    // of credits.  The update is done by first converting the letter grade
    // into a numeric value (A = 4.0, B = 3.0, etc.).  The new GPA is 
    // calculated using the formula:
    //
    //            (oldGPA * old_total_credits) + (numeric_grade * cr)
    //   newGPA = ---------------------------------------------------
    //                        old_total_credits + cr
    //
    // Finally, the total credits is updated (to old_total_credits + cr)

    void print() const;  
    // Prints out the student to standard output in the format:
    //   ID,credits,GPA
    // Note: the end-of-line is NOT printed after the student information 

  private:
    int studentID;
    int credits;
    double GPA;
};

#endif
```

Comment: Do you mean to be including `.cpp` files?

Comment: Why are you including cpp files?

Comment: We need to see the contents of SortedList.h

Comment: Have you tried using clang?  It usually gives better error messages in the form of "did you mean `foo`?"

Comment: Is this your actual code?  There seems to be a number of small problems.  Like "x = new Student(num)".

Comment: Yes I am sure there is cause I just started my debugging process. If you would like to point out some other errors I would be greatful for that help as well.

Comment: I updated my error message. Might help for recognizing the problem

Comment: Try a forward declaration of SortedList just after "using namespace std;" -- "class SortedList;"  It shouldn't be necessary, but it may make the problem more obvious.

Comment: i'm using g++ 4.1.2 and I tried the "class SortedList;" declaration but i got the same error

Comment: Is your "#ifndef STUDENT_H" really at the end of SortedList.h, or is that a formatting problem?

Comment: Since you include nothing else in your example, you actually don't have a namespace `std`, so I wonder why it doesn't fail right there. Otherwise, your example works for me (MSVC 2008, after removing the C11-style loops)

Comment: This isn't the real code as `using namespace std;` would fail. Post a minimal example which still exhibits the problem. Cut everything out. If you're worried about deleting code, learn to use version control like mercurial or git.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to include .h files, not .cpp files:

```
#include "Student.h"
#include "SortedList.h"
```

Without more code it's hard to speculate what else the issue may be.

Answer (score 2):

There seem to be a number of problems with your main function.  This is more correct:

```
int main() {
    SortedList *list = new SortedList; //1
    Student create[100]; //2
    int num = 100000;

    for (Student &x : create) { //3
        x = Student(num); //4
        num += 100;
    }

    for (Student &x : create) //5
        list->insert(&x);

    delete list;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @PatMurray: I've modified my answer.

Comment: Thanks. I also updated my error message above. Cause I am still getting the error even with the code you gave me.

Comment: @PatMurray: I've compiled the code using g++ 4.6.3 without error.

Comment: I'm using g++ 4.1.2 and it still is not working. Thanks for trying it out though

Answer (score 1):

You need to include the header which defines the class `SortedList` in your cpp file.
On a side note I don't know why you include a `cpp` file in your program, Please don't do that.

**EDIT:**  To your updated Q.
If you already include the geader file which defines the class `SortedList` in the `cpp`file which gives you the error, Probably you have wrapped up your class in a namespace.If so, You should use fully qualified name for the class or use an using declaration for the class name in your main cpp file.

Comment: I have not created a namespace myself in this program. And I can not think of which namespace would be appropriate

Answer (score 1):

I suspect `SORTEDLIST_H` is defined before `SortedList.h` is processed..

check if you have defined the same `SORTEDLIST_H` in Student.h...

Update1:
Try adding these flags along with your g++ compilation statement

```
   g++ -USORTEDLIST_H -USTUDENT_H <fileNames>
```

Comment: I put the missing top of Student.h up. both .h files are complete up above

Comment: If your comment is true, how do I fix that?

Comment: what happened with this flag compilation?

Comment: I had to leave a linux system that i was working at so i will get back tomorrow

Answer (score 0):

I suspect `SortedList` has been declared in a namespace.

Example:

**SortedList.h**

```
namespace MON {
class SortedList { ... };
} // << MON
```

**main.cpp**

```
int main() {
    MON::SortedList *list = new MON::SortedList();  //This is line 17
    ....
}
```